# Flickr API - Photos Search, excluding tags: Am I doing this wrong?

Tags: api, search, tags, flickr

So, I'm trying to pull all photos of a specific user's account via the `flickr.photos.search method`, but I want to exclude photos with a particular tag. The related documentation page states that "*You can exclude results that match a term by prepending it with a - character.*" ... Well, I tried implementing that option but what get in return is only one photo (even though [there are several photos with the tag in question](http://www.flickr.com/photos/68293262@N03/tags/blog/)) and that result remains the same whether that specific photo has the tag in question or not AND whether or not I use the "-" option to exclude that tag rather than include it. I also tried the `text` method with the same exact result. Here's my REST call:

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photos.search&api_key='.$api_key.'&user_id='.$user_id.'&tag_mode=any&tags=-blog&extras=url_o,url_t&format=json
```

And here is the page where I'm trying to get this all working:

http://corazonbrew.com/temp/

Anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Well I dunno what the hell is going on, but I just added `var_dump()` call to show the results array, and suddenly things appear correct .. Well, almost- I now see the photos with the tag in question, but I'm using the "-" option to try to exclude those images, still to no avail.

I have to run out for a few hours right now, but will do some more testing and report back ASAP.

Comment: OK, I'm back. I removed the `var_dump()` and I'm thankfully still seeing more than one photo, but the exclusion option is still not working .. any thoughts on the matter?

Comment: Finally found some other mentions of this issue, but still no fix that works for me:

---
http://www.flickr.com/groups/api/discuss/72157625456418732/

---
http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?804847-Flicker-API-exclude-picture-with-a-certain-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the answer in the [Flickr discussion board](http://www.flickr.com/groups/api/discuss/72157625456418732/) I linked to earlier is proving true. In order to use the exclusion option, there has to also be at least one other, non-excluded tag. Well, that is just not good enough for me.

A couple of friends tell me this is a longstanding bug that will not be fixed anytime soon, if ever. But those friends also kindly reminded me of my n00bishness- this whole time I thought I needed to affect the feed to get the desired output. I totally was not realizing I could just use some good ol' PHP if statements to weed out what I don't want.